# Error al comunicar controlador hijo con su controlador padre

Tags: angularjs, formularios

Estoy creando mi primera aplicación con AngularJS, y me ha salido un error al que no le he encontrado solución. El problema radica en que al momento de generar los valores en el formulario, la tabla no los muestra.

Este es el código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appRegistro">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>App de Prueba</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="ControladorAplicacion as cntrl">
<div id="cuerpo" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h3>App de Prueba</h3>
        <!--Seccion de la app que acepta la informacion del votante-->
        <form name="forma_datos" ng-controller="ControladorRegistro as reg" ng-submit="reg.agregarRegistro(votante)">
            <p>Cedula: <input ng-model="reg.registro.cedula" type="text" ></input></p>
            <p>Telefono: <input ng-model="reg.registro.telefono" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Nombre Completo: <input ng-model="reg.registro.nombre" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Municipio: <input ng-model="reg.registro.municipio" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Parroquia: <input ng-model="reg.registro.parroquia" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Centro: <input ng-model="reg.registro.centro" type="text"></p>
            <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="expression">Agregar</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--Tabla para la presentacion de valores ingresados-->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedula</td>
                <td>Nombre Completo</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td>Municipio</td>
                <td>Parroquia</td>
                <td>Centro</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="registro in cntrl.registros">
                <td>{{reg.registro.cedula}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.registro.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.registro.telefono}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.registro.municipio}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.registro.parroquia}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.registro.centro}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el controlador:

```
(function(){
//Inicializador de la aplicacion
var app = angular.module('appRegistro', []);

//Inicializador del controlador
app.controller('ControladorAplicacion', function(){
    this.registros = regs;
});

//Controlador para la función
app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function(){
    this.registro = {};

    this.agregarRegistro = function(votante){
        votante.registros.push(this.registro);
        this.registro = {};         
    };
});

var regs = [{
    cedula : '10111000',
    nombre : 'Luis Lopez',
    telefono : '04141230011'
}];

})();
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se si esto será de ayuda pero parece ser que cuando declaras la función, hay delante un "(" prueba a quitarlo

Comment: @Meyado ese paréntesis es válido y lo que hace es formar un [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu tienes dos controllers, uno dentro de otro. Tu problema radica en que tienes que comunicar dos `$scope` diferentes (de hijo a padre) y generalmente la forma de hacer esto esa una de las siguientes

1. En el controller hijo inyectando $scope y navegando hacia el padre con la propiedad `$parent`.
2. En la vista, usando una [expresión](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) y referenciando el valor deseado en el padre.
3. Usando [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) desde el controller hijo para enviarle los datos a su padre usando un evento

**Solución 1**

En el controller sería algo como esto

```
app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.registro = {};

    vm.agregarRegistro = function () {
        // cntrl es el mismo valor que especificaste en controllerAs
        $scope.$parent.cntrl.registros.push(vm.registro);
        vm.registro = {};
    };
});
```

```js
(function() {
  //Inicializador de la aplicacion
  var app = angular.module('appRegistro', []);

  //Inicializador del controlador
  app.controller('ControladorAplicacion', function() {
    var cntrl = this;
    cntrl.registros = regs;
  });

  //Controlador para la función
  app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function($scope) {
    var reg = this;
    reg.registro = {};

    reg.agregarRegistro = function() {
      // cntrl es el mismo valor que especificaste en controllerAs
      $scope.$parent.cntrl.registros.push(reg.registro);
      reg.registro = {};
    };
  });

  var regs = [{
    cedula: '10111000',
    nombre: 'Luis Lopez',
    telefono: '04141230011'
  }];

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appRegistro" ng-controller="ControladorAplicacion as cntrl">
  <div id="cuerpo" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h3>App de Prueba</h3>
      <!--Seccion de la app que acepta la informacion del votante-->
      <form name="forma_datos" ng-controller="ControladorRegistro as reg" ng-submit="reg.agregarRegistro()">
        <label>Cedula:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.cedula" type="text">
        <label>Telefono:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.telefono" type="text">
        <label>Nombre Completo:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.nombre" type="text">
        <label>Municipio:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.municipio" type="text">
        <label>Parroquia:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.parroquia" type="text">
        <label>Centro:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.centro" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Tabla para la presentacion de valores ingresados-->
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
      <td>Cedula</td>
      <td>Nombre Completo</td>
      <td>Telefono</td>
      <td>Municipio</td>
      <td>Parroquia</td>
      <td>Centro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="registro in cntrl.registros">
      <td>{{registro.cedula}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.telefono}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.municipio}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.parroquia}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.centro}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

A mí realmente no me gusta esta forma. Sólo mira a la expresión `$scope.$parent.cntrl.registros` para que veas que difícil de mantener será cuando tengas que usarla frecuentemente.

**Solución 2**

Le puedes pasar el valor correcto desde la vista ya que aquí puedes referenciar directamente el controller padre

```
<form name="forma_datos" ng-controller="ControladorRegistro as reg" 
    ng-submit="reg.agregarRegistro(cntrl.registros)">
    <!-- Usas la variable cntrl para referenciar el controller correcto -->
    <!-- Resto de los campos -->
</form>
```

Luego en en controller sería

```
vm.agregarRegistro = function (registros) {
    // La referencia correcta nos llega como un parámetro de la funcion
    registros.push(vm.registro);
    vm.registro = {};
};
```

```js
(function() {
  //Inicializador de la aplicacion
  var app = angular.module('appRegistro', []);

  //Inicializador del controlador
  app.controller('ControladorAplicacion', function() {
    var cntrl = this;
    cntrl.registros = regs;
  });

  //Controlador para la función
  app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function() {
    var reg = this;
    reg.registro = {};

    reg.agregarRegistro = function(registros) {
      // se obtiene la referencia correcta por parámetros
      registros.push(reg.registro);
      reg.registro = {};
    };
  });

  var regs = [{
    cedula: '10111000',
    nombre: 'Luis Lopez',
    telefono: '04141230011'
  }];

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appRegistro" ng-controller="ControladorAplicacion as cntrl">
  <div id="cuerpo" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h3>App de Prueba</h3>
      <!--Seccion de la app que acepta la informacion del votante-->
      <form name="forma_datos" ng-controller="ControladorRegistro as reg" ng-submit="reg.agregarRegistro(cntrl.registros)">
        <label>Cedula:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.cedula" type="text">
        <label>Telefono:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.telefono" type="text">
        <label>Nombre Completo:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.nombre" type="text">
        <label>Municipio:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.municipio" type="text">
        <label>Parroquia:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.parroquia" type="text">
        <label>Centro:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.centro" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Tabla para la presentacion de valores ingresados-->
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
      <td>Cedula</td>
      <td>Nombre Completo</td>
      <td>Telefono</td>
      <td>Municipio</td>
      <td>Parroquia</td>
      <td>Centro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="registro in cntrl.registros">
      <td>{{registro.cedula}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.telefono}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.municipio}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.parroquia}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.centro}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Solución 3**

Esta es en mi opinión la más recomendada cuando se intenta la comunicación hijo-padre ya que puede pasar que en el futuro insertes un controller en el medio y las demás soluciones presenten problemas.

```
app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.registro = {};

    vm.agregarRegistro = function() {
        // Se emite el evento al presionar el boton
        $scope.$emit('nuevo_registro', vm.registro);
        vm.registro = {};         
    };
});

app.controller('ControladorAplicacion', function($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.registros = regs;

    // En caso que se reciba el evento insertamos el nuevo registro
    $scope.$on('nuevo_registro', function(evt, nuevo) {
        vm.registros.push(nuevo);
    })
});
```

```js
(function() {
  //Inicializador de la aplicacion
  var app = angular.module('appRegistro', []);

  //Inicializador del controlador

  app.controller('ControladorAplicacion', function($scope) {
    var cntrl = this;
    cntrl.registros = regs;

    // En caso que se reciba el evento insertamos el nuevo registro
    $scope.$on('nuevo_registro', function(evt, nuevo) {
      cntrl.registros.push(nuevo);
    })
  });

  //Controlador para la función
  app.controller('ControladorRegistro', function($scope) {
    var reg = this;
    reg.registro = {};

    reg.agregarRegistro = function() {
      // Se emite el evento al presionar el boton
      $scope.$emit('nuevo_registro', reg.registro);
      reg.registro = {};
    };
  });

  var regs = [{
    cedula: '10111000',
    nombre: 'Luis Lopez',
    telefono: '04141230011'
  }];

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appRegistro" ng-controller="ControladorAplicacion as cntrl">
  <div id="cuerpo" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h3>App de Prueba</h3>
      <!--Seccion de la app que acepta la informacion del votante-->
      <form name="forma_datos" ng-controller="ControladorRegistro as reg" ng-submit="reg.agregarRegistro()">
        <label>Cedula:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.cedula" type="text">
        <label>Telefono:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.telefono" type="text">
        <label>Nombre Completo:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.nombre" type="text">
        <label>Municipio:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.municipio" type="text">
        <label>Parroquia:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.parroquia" type="text">
        <label>Centro:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="reg.registro.centro" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Tabla para la presentacion de valores ingresados-->
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
      <td>Cedula</td>
      <td>Nombre Completo</td>
      <td>Telefono</td>
      <td>Municipio</td>
      <td>Parroquia</td>
      <td>Centro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="registro in cntrl.registros">
      <td>{{registro.cedula}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.telefono}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.municipio}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.parroquia}}</td>
      <td>{{registro.centro}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Por último como nota personal te corregí algunos errores que te los menciono a continuación

- No uses `<input></input>`, esto es ilegal. La forma correcta es `<input />` o sólo `<input>` en html5
- Si estás usando bootstrap usa las [clases](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) de formularios y de tablas para mejorar la apariencia de tu interfaz
- No uses `this` solamente en tus controllers. Puedes perder esta referencia fácilmente en eventos y otros lugares. Asígnalo a una variable, ej `vm`, o el nombre que le pusiste en `controllerAs` y usa la variable directamente.
- La directiva `ng-repeat` te crea una variable y un nuevo `$scope` en cada iteración. Usa esa variable para referenciar los datos o tendrás que navegar hacia el padre (controller "ControladorRegistro") usando `$parent`. En lugar de `{{reg.registro.cedula}}` es `{{registro.cedula}}`

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en tu forma de llamar a los objetos a través de `ngRepeat`. A ngRepeat le estás diciendo que itere sobre el objeto `cntrl.registros` (que según estoy viendo, no estoy muy seguro de que lo hayas creado) devolviendo los valores bajo el nombre de "registro". Aquí, la forma correcta de mostrarlos no es llamar a `reg.registro.<campo>`, sino a `registro.<campo>`

```
<tr ng-repeat="registro in cntrl.registros">
  <td>{{registro.cedula}}</td>
  <td>{{registro.nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{registro.telefono}}</td>
  <td>{{registro.municipio}}</td>
  <td>{{registro.parroquia}}</td>
  <td>{{registro.centro}}</td>
</tr>
```

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) y que te asegures de estar creando el objeto correctamente en tu controlador.

Un saludo.